# is there a way to switch a component from full screen to two rows in react

Tags: reactjs, materialize

(new to react so my question might sound dumb)

I am trying to build a react project that has a list. the list should cover the entire width before one of the list items is clicked. I would like for the component to move from full screen to half screen when one of the list items is clicked and display some new content on the right side with the list on the left.

So, in essence what i am looking for after clicking is

```
<div className="main-component">
            <div className="row">
                <div className=" left-component">
                    <DataList data={data} />
                </div>
                <div className="right-component">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/data/'component={DefaultPage} />
                        <Route path='/home/datadetails/:id'component={DataContent} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

Before clicking, list should be full screen width, after clicking, list should move to left half of screen and the content of the list item to be displayed to the right half of the screen.

Please assist.

Comment: I think CSS will hopefully solve your requirement

Comment: CSS cant change the components on the screen. it has got to be something with the Switch. That's where I am stuck

Comment: yeah css alone can't to what you need to do is have two components one is that displaying list (i think that is the one present now) create another component that will get the props from list component and display . Let me know if u didn't get clearly

Comment: I already have the component that displays the props. So how do I move the list from full screen to half and have the other half display the props. like the gmail preview pane works